# Vuejs/Stripe Elements - credit card number disappears on component change

Tags: vue.js, stripe-payments

I've created a sample Vuejs project where you can switch between two components. In the first component, a user enters a username and a credit card number to create their account, and in the second component the user verifies the information they entered:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-u8w1m

I'm using Stripe Elements to process my payments. When a user enters the relevant information in component 1, they hit *Next* to move onto component 2, where they can look over the information to see if everything is correct.

But what if, on component 2, the user realizes that they entered something wrong and need to change something? Well, they can hit *Back* to go back to component 1 to make the necessary changes.

So here is the problem: I'm using *keep-alive* for the components, and when the user hits *Back*, the username is still in the input field, but the credit card number is gone.

I would like to have a separate "confirmation component" where a user can look over all the information they have entered is accurate, but it is annoying if every time the user hits *Back* all the credit card information always disappears. It seems like bad UX design.

Is this the intended behavior for Stripe Elements? Or is there a way around this issue?

Comment: I don't have an explanation for why it's happening but one workaround would be to use `v-show` instead of `keep-alive`

Comment: That works, thanks. It is not how I would want to swap between components, but at least it works properly now.